Problems occur when SQL script tries to run in Azure liquibase
Using the following SQL script, I scheduled to run Azure liquibase:
UPDATE MT
SET SourceID = 0
FROM Mas_Test MT
INNER JOIN Mas_TestType TT ON MT.ID = TT.ID
WHERE TT.Instrument = 'FX-OFFSET' 
  AND MT.SOURCEID = 1

We need to update the total number of record 84198
But I am getting the following error (Run liquibase script)

Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint


